# Route not resolving in angularjs 1.2.15

Tags: angularjs, express, ngroute

I have a route
`/hungry/hippo/nom-nom-nom`
that maps great.  No problem.

Add an extra slash
`/hungry/hippo/nom-nom-nom/to-full-barf`

The latter does not resolve and I can't figure why

```
.when('/hungry/hippo/nom-nom-nom/to-full-barf', {
        templateUrl: '/views/muyHungryHippo.html',
      })
```

Just adding the extra depth `to-full-barf` does not resolve.

any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
Did more digging and the call is not going through `express.js`.  I think the problem is not in angular but in express.

Comment: Is this your full code? There's an extraneous trailing comma in your object literal.

Comment: this was just what i had in the routes.  simply adding the extra url parameter messes things up.  but now im thinking its in express.js instead of angular

Comment: What i understand is, you are little confused with working together with Angular and Express routes. Since you have angular, so it's a Single Page application and routing in front end is managed by Angular ngroute. Whereas the Express routes are nothing but REST end points. So forget about Express for a moment and make your Angular routes work, and then you can call REST API's with either $http or $resource.

Comment: If i create a button in `/hungry/hippo/nom-nom-nom` and make it so that when I click on it takes me to `/hungry/hippo/nom-nom-nom/to-full-barf` it works just fine.  When i refresh the page with the same url it does not load.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an `AngularJS` *issue* but more like an `Express` routing priority *issue*. Defining the route `/hungry/hippo/nom-nom-nom/to-full-barf` in `Express` before `/hungry/hippo/nom-nom-nom` should help.

And yes, I'm emphasising *issue* because this isn't an issue in the first place.

`Express` maps routes with the same order of priority as their order of creation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This is not the case at all.  All the routes in express start with `/api/v8/...`.  On the angular side i have the `/hungry/hippo/...`.  It is only when I add the extra path that things break down.